# Insert data to one class with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a working row clone scenario (multiple dynamic rows) after an inventory number is confirmed from mysql database. What I want to do (but can't figure out), is how to insert the inventory data to only the next DIV `batch_item_desc` which has the same class name as all because of the clone.  What keeps happening is the inventory data is inserted to every row, and not "this" row.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
    <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field row">
        <div class="col-md-2 item_num_div">
            <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm batch_item_num" 
                   name="item_num[]">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 batch_item_desc"></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-field btn-sm">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- End Div multi-field && row -->
    </div>  <!-- End div multi-fieldS -->
    </div>  <!-- end div wrapper -->
```

**jQuery:**

```
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);

        $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
            if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
        });
        //-------- Batch Inventory --------------
        $(".batch_item_num", $(this)).keyup(function(e) {

            var item_num = $(this).val();
            if (item_num.length == 9) {
                $.get('inventory/api.php', {"action":"batch_item_num","item_num":item_num},
                    function(data, result) {

            var desc = data;

            $('.item_num_div').next('.batch_item_desc').html(desc);


        $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();

                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I can't for the life of me get this line working to display inventory data for JUST the single row in question, it inserts to all rows.

```
$('.item_num_div').next('.batch_item_desc').html(desc);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the current jQuery element `$(this)` instead of the class `item_num_div` selector that will select all elements with this class :

```
$(this).next('.batch_item_desc').html(desc);
```

Also you should go up to the parent `row` then select the `batch_item_desc` since it not a sibling of `batch_item_num` :

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('.batch_item_desc').html(desc);
```

Note that the `$(this)` inside the `$.get` callback doesn't refer to the current element no more, you should store the `$(this)` in another variable before the request e.g :

```
var item_num = $(this).val();
var _this = $(this);
```

Then use this variable instead of `$(this)` inside the callback :

```
_this.closest('.row').find('.batch_item_desc').html(desc);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had tried this before but it seems to not do anything. I confirmed with alert(desc) that the data is there.

Comment: Check my update, you're trying to treat `batch_item_desc` as sibling when it's not.

Comment: This makes sense, but it's not working. The next row gets cloned properly, but no data is displayed.

Comment: Emm not sure.. are you sure that the `desc` is not empty :(

Comment: Yes, I did an alert(desc) and the data is there.  Same data that does show  if i do "$('.item_num_div').next('.batch_item_desc').html(desc);"  but shows on all rows.

Comment: Yes that totally logic i just noticed that you're using an http request, i'll updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry i've just fixed another typo in my answer `_this.closest('.row')` (note the class selector '.' before the `row`).

Comment: BINGO. so that fixed that issue for now. I wonder (without being too anoying), the clone now clones the first row DIV data from (batch_item_desc). The input data is cleared as expected.  Suggestion on also clearing the DIV data for the newest inserted row? Thanks for everything!

Comment: Welcome anytime.. i'm not sure how the structure looks like but i could give you an idea :) try to use `empty()` of `html()` on all the divs of the cloned div, e.g : `$("selector div").empty()`.

Comment: Found my answer. Thought I'd Share:          `                        var clone = $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
                        div.closest('.row').find('.batch_item_desc').html(desc);
                        clone.closest('.row').find('.batch_item_desc').html('');
`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.first()` to only select the first element in the set of matched elements:

```
$('.item_num_div').next('.batch_item_desc').first().html(desc);
```

Comment: This still inserted the data into ALL rows, and not just the single row in question.